# PHP form validation with the same value

Tags: php

I faced a problem validating my PHP form where I described *from* location and *to* location, where they can't be same.

```
if (!isset($_POST["from"])){
    $errorfrom="Select Departure Time";
    $err = true;
}
else{
    $from=$_POST["from"];
}
        
if (!isset($_POST["to"])){
    $errorto="Select Departure Time";
    $err = true;
}
else{
    $to=$_POST["to"];
}
```

In the database, *from* and *to* are same, but they can't be same:
[image: here in the database from and to is same. but they cant be same.]

[image: here from and to destination cant be same]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow users to choose same from and to location is not server stuff. In any case you must check locations like this:

```
if (!isset($_POST["from"])){      
    $errorfrom="Select Departure Time";
    $err = true;
}else{
    $from=$_POST["from"];
}

if (!isset($_POST["to"])){
    $errorto="Select Departure Time";
    $err = true;
}else{
    $to=$_POST["to"];
}

if(strcmp($from, $to) !== 0){ //note that strcmp is case sensitive
    $errorDescription="From and to location can not be the same";
    $error = true;
}
```